# Oracle SQL: Group by not working with aggregates in CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL query is currently:

```
SELECT ARINVT.CLASS,
 ARINVT.ITEMNO,
 ARINVT.DESCRIP,
 ARINVT.ONHAND,
 CASE 
 WHEN DAY_USE_TOTAL.CUM_MAT_QTY IS NULL THEN 0
 ELSE SUM (DAY_USE_TOTAL.TOT_MAT_QTY) END "Material Usage"

FROM IQMS.ARINVT ARINVT
 LEFT JOIN IQMS.DAY_USE_TOTAL DAY_USE_TOTAL
    ON ARINVT.ID = DAY_USE_TOTAL.ARINVT_ID


WHERE CLASS = 'PL'
GROUP BY ARINVT.ID,
     ARINVT.CLASS,
     ARINVT.ITEMNO,
     ARINVT.DESCRIP,
     ARINVT.ONHAND

ORDER BY ARINVT.ITEMNO
```

I'm currently getting the error `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.
When I remove the case statement and just have the `SUM()`:

```
SELECT ARINVT.CLASS,
 ARINVT.ITEMNO,
 ARINVT.DESCRIP,
 ARINVT.ONHAND,
 SUM (DAY_USE_TOTAL.TOT_MAT_QTY) 

FROM IQMS.ARINVT ARINVT
 LEFT JOIN IQMS.DAY_USE_TOTAL DAY_USE_TOTAL
    ON ARINVT.ID = DAY_USE_TOTAL.ARINVT_ID


WHERE CLASS = 'PL'
GROUP BY ARINVT.ID,
     ARINVT.CLASS,
     ARINVT.ITEMNO,
     ARINVT.DESCRIP,
     ARINVT.ONHAND

ORDER BY ARINVT.ITEMNO
```

It works perfectly fine. Why is this? I think it would be because the `CASE` statement can return 0 which doesn't work with the `GROUP BY`, but even having both returning as aggregates doesn't seem to fix this. How can I resolve this? I'm try to use a subquery at the moment but at the moment not much success with it.

Comment: You are trying to combine an aggregate and a non-aggregate in the same column, therefore it will fail.
Try adding `DAY_USE_TOTAL.CUM_MAT_QTY` to your group

Comment: I understand that can happen. I've tried replacing the 0 with something like SUM(DAY_USE_TOTAL.TOT_MAT_QTY) as well just to test it but still gives the same error.

Comment: Can we have sample data and expected outputs?

Comment: Case _expression_, not _statement_...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
 SUM (CASE WHEN DAY_USE_TOTAL.CUM_MAT_QTY IS NULL THEN 0
 ELSE DAY_USE_TOTAL.TOT_MAT_QTY END) "Material Usage"
```

Comment: nice and crispy :)

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
SELECT ARINVT.CLASS,
 ARINVT.ITEMNO,
 ARINVT.DESCRIP,
 ARINVT.ONHAND,
 SUM (CASE WHEN DAY_USE_TOTAL.CUM_MAT_QTY IS NULL THEN 0
 ELSE DAY_USE_TOTAL.TOT_MAT_QTY END) "Material Usage"

FROM IQMS.ARINVT ARINVT
 LEFT JOIN IQMS.DAY_USE_TOTAL DAY_USE_TOTAL
    ON ARINVT.ID = DAY_USE_TOTAL.ARINVT_ID


WHERE CLASS = 'PL'
GROUP BY ARINVT.ID,
     ARINVT.CLASS,
     ARINVT.ITEMNO,
     ARINVT.DESCRIP,
     ARINVT.ONHAND

ORDER BY ARINVT.ITEMNO
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped!